# How can I find the current function's closure when debugging JavaScript in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, closures

I am debugging a React JS application through VSCode and Chrome. At a breakpoint a variable I am interested in is visible in the Closure section of the variables list. At other levels of the stack trace the variable is not available. The function is defined at the top level of its JS file, and I can't see where the closure is defined, and in particular where the variable is first assigned. Called from elsewhere the closure scoped variable is different and I can't see why.

Is there any way in VS Code Debugging or Chrome Dev Tools to see where the closure scope was defined?

As a simple example, if debugging the JS code below and hitting a breakpoint at `a=1` is there any way to identify the closureScope variable in which a is defined? In the real example the function and closure scoped variables are not obviously contained in any other functions or blocks, but my understanding of modern JS and closures is limited and I may be missing something obvious.

```
function main() {
  let closureScope = (
    function() {
    var a = 0;
    return {
      inside1: function() {
        a = 1;
      },
      inside2: function() {
        a = 2;
      }
    };
  })();

  closureScope.inside1();
  closureScope.inside2();
}

main();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use debugger in `vscode` or `chrome`

- Add a breakpoint in code, you can click on the red dot in the left side of your file to add a break point
- Or use `debugger;` where you want breakpoint
- On the left hand side expand the `variable` list and than `closureScope` to see your value in that particular scope

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about the [[Scopes]] array under the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the alternative with Chrome dev tools

[image]